# How to dynamically update mass/center of mass/inertia during Gazebo sim

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Components in the URDF files can be assigned static mass, center of mass, and inertial matrix.

Is there a way to update those values dynamically once the Gazebo simulation environment has started up?

For example, say I had a fuel tank on a robot and I wanted to decrease the weight and center of mass of the tank as a function of engine power output over time. Or maybe I have a robot expelling a liquid from a holding tank or sucking up a liquid into a holding tank.

I can't seem to find a solution to this in the ROS docs.

Thank you,
Randy

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258673/how-to-dynamically-update-mass/center-of-mass/inertia-during-gazebo-sim/) by [r0salesr](https://answers.ros.org/users/29945/r0salesr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2017-04-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yep...just needed to look a little longer. The GetMass() and SetMass functions in the [Gazebo inertial physics library](http://osrf-distributions.s3.amazonaws.com/gazebo/api/dev/classgazebo_1_1physics_1_1Inertial.html) had what I wanted.

Thanks!
Randy

---

Originally posted by [r0salesr](https://answers.ros.org/users/29945/r0salesr/) with karma: 26 on 2017-04-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0